# Proftpd, дает читать файлы и директории, но не дает Upload... помогите с конфигом

Tags: ftp, upload, config

Ситуация такая...
на VPS установил Proftpd, установился...
дабы не заморачиваться с пользователями, сделал, чтобы можно было заходить из под рута, сделал, заходит... могу скачать файлы, вот закачать не дает, выдает, что нет доступа!  такой выходит ответ:

```
220 ProFTPD 1.3.5rc3 Server (FTP server) [***.***.***.***] USER root 331 Password required for root PASS ******  230 User root logged in TYPE I 200 Type set to I CWD /var/www/SITENAME/www 250 CWD command successful PWD 257 "/var/www/SITENAME/www" is the current directory CWD /var/www/SITENAME/www 250 CWD command successful PORT 192,168,1,97,206,224 200 PORT command successful STOR info.php.new 550 info.php.new: Permission denied PORT 192,168,1,97,206,225 200 PORT command successful STOR info.php.new
```

Содержание Proftpd.conf:

```
 1. Include /etc/proftpd/modules.conf
 2. UseIPv6                         off
 3. IdentLookups                    off
 4. ServerName                      "FTP server"
 5. ServerType                      standalone
 6. DeferWelcome                    off
 7. MultilineRFC2228                on
 8. DefaultServer                   on
 9. ShowSymlinks                    on
 10. TimeoutNoTransfer               600
 11. TimeoutStalled                  600
 12. TimeoutIdle                     1200
 13. DisplayLogin                    welcome.msg
 14. DisplayChdir                    .message true
 15. ListOptions                     "-l"
 16. DenyFilter                      \*.*/
 17. Port                            [СКРЫТО]
 18. MaxInstances                    15
 19. User                            proftpd
 20. Group                           nogroup
 21. Umask                           022
 22. AllowOverwrite                  on
 23. TransferLog /var/log/proftpd/xferlog
 24. SystemLog   /var/log/proftpd/proftpd.log 
 25. <IfModule mod_quotatab.c> QuotaEngine off </IfModule>
 26. <IfModule mod_ratio.c>Ratios off</IfModule>
 27. <IfModule mod_delay.c>DelayEngine on</IfModule>
 28. <IfModule mod_ctrls.c> ControlsEngine        off ControlsMaxClients    2 ControlsLog           /var/log/proftpd/controls.log ControlsInterval      5 ControlsSocket        /var/run/proftpd/proftpd.sock </IfModule>
 29. <IfModule mod_ctrls_admin.c> AdminControlsEngine off </IfModule>
 30. RootLogin on
 31. <Limit READ WRITE DIRS> Allowuser root </Limit>
```

Подскажите, где я сплоховал... ведь устанавливаю FTP сервер не так часто :)